# pnpm: How to install the same dependency in different versions?

Tags: npm, package.json, pnpm

When installing a package with pnpm I get this error:

```
ERR_PNPM_PEER_DEP_ISSUES  Unmet peer dependencies

tinacms
└─┬ @tinacms/toolkit
  ├─┬ @react-aria/listbox
  │ └── ✕ unmet peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0-rc.1": found 18.2.0
  └─┬ @udecode/plate-headless
    └─┬ @udecode/plate-alignment
      └─┬ @udecode/plate-core
        └─┬ @radix-ui/react-slot
          ├── ✕ unmet peer react@"^16.8 || ^17.0": found 18.2.0
          └─┬ @radix-ui/react-compose-refs
            └── ✕ unmet peer react@"^16.8 || ^17.0": found 18.2.0
```

I am already using react in the project (hence it found 18.2.0), so I can't just install it a second time.

I looked into creating aliases, but this won't help me because in my dependencies, react is imported just as `react` - no way to change this to `react-latest` or similar. I then tried my luck with [pnpm overrides](https://pnpm.io/package_json#pnpmoverrides).

> This field allows you to instruct pnpm to override any dependency in the dependency graph. This is useful to enforce all your packages to use a single version of a dependency, backport a fix, or replace a dependency with a fork.

I tried it like this in my `package.json`:

```
"pnpm": {
  "overrides": {
    "react": "18.2.0"
  }
}
```

I was hoping this would be a clean way to deal with this, but the warning is still show. Seems like my last chance is accepting it and adding `strict-peer-dependencies=false` to my .npmrc to stop this to fail the install process. But is there maybe a cleaner way to deal with this?